# Coloring the header using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the color of the header. there is not color at all.

I'm new to html and css so i'm trying very hard to copy a site to learn more by doing and running into problems. First question for me, i hope you can help.

```css
header {
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 120px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block
}
}
.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.logo a {
  color: #ffd800;
}
.logo span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.baseline {
  line-height: 120px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px
}
.phone {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 120px;
}
.phone a {
  color: #ffd800;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!--nav#menu.navbar.navbar-fixed-top-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#">bureau<span>travaux</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="baseline">Un interlocuteur unique pour tous vos travaux</div>
    <div class="phone"><a href="callto://0139239510">01 39 23 95 10</a>
      <a href="http://www.bureau-travaux.com/en/index.html" class="lang-button en"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code in a snippet/code block/jsfiddle etc instead of as plain text?

Comment: Your code works for me, by the way. It shows up gray: https://jsfiddle.net/3a514y8g/

Comment: Thank you all for your help and comments, I found where the problem was coming from, and yes the piece of code that is edited here work! Thanks to Pangloss for jsfiddle, i will use it now.

Comment: Could you mark the green checkbox under the answer so we can close? Thank you! And good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO you want to change the color from gray to a different one?

```
header {
   background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
   ...
   ...
}
```

You can if you change the values here: `rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5)`. In this case that corresponds to a dark gray with a 50% background. If you CHANGE that it can be any color.

[This tool](http://www.hexcolortool.com) can help you get the code for the colour you want.

See the Pen [vgGvag](http://codepen.io/scoopzilla/pen/vgGvag/) by Sean Rawles ([@scoopzilla](http://codepen.io/scoopzilla)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).